# Table taking up full width

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I am looking to adjust this table in two ways:

-Firstly, I would like the second `=` to be more to the right, next to the `$P_{S}(K|GB)$`.
-Secondly, I would like the table to take up as much width as possible, such that it almost forms one single line (it won't really be a single line as the text is just too long for that, which is the whole reason I am constructing this table like this).

Thank you for your insight.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lllcrrrcc}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{$P_{S}(A|GB)$} & $=$ & & $=$ & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$P_{S}(K|GB)$} &     \multirow{2}{*}{for} & \multirow{2}{*}{$p>\frac{1}{2}$}\\
 & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$p(1-e_{1})+(1-p)(e_{1})$} & $>$ & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$p(1-e_{2})+(1-p)(e_{2})$} & & & 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Receiver's conditional payoffs}
\label{eq:Label}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in the following manner:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{llrcrrrrc}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{$P_{S}(A|GG) =$} & $1$ & $>$ & $1$ & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$= P_{S}(K|GG)$} & \hspace{2mm} for & any value
\vspace{4mm}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{$P_{S}(A|GB) =$} & & & & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$= P_{S}(K|GB)$} &     \hspace{2mm} \multirow{2}{*}{for} & \multirow{2}{*}{$p>\frac{1}{2}$}\\
\hspace{8mm} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$p(1-e_{1})+(1-p)(e_{1})$} & $>$ & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$p(1-e_{2})+(1-p)(e_{2})$} & \hspace{8mm} & & 
\vspace{4mm}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{$P_{S}(A|BB) =$} & $0$ & $>$ & $0$ & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$= P_{S}(K|BB)$} & \hspace{2mm} for & any value
\vspace{4mm}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Receiver's conditional payoffs}
\label{eq:Label}
\end{table}
```

If anyone knows a better/sleeker method, please let me know.